# reports in ASP.NET MVC1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, report

What is the best way to create reports in ASP.NET MVC1? Any link for learn how to create reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create `.rdlc` files, which can be presented in ASP.NET by using the [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx) control. Everything you need is already included in Visual Studio.

Tutorials can be found by googling for `ReportViewer`, [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671.aspx) or on http://www.gotreportviewer.com/.

Comment: Is the prblem(for this solution), if i use LINQ

Answer (score 1):

I found the following app from codeplex really helpful when i was trying to figure out how to do reporting in asp.net mvc.  -> [Sample Report Solution](http://mvcrdlc.codeplex.com/)

Hope this helps!